# Get product id from wishlist remove item event in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento

When I remove an item from wishlist, I need to get the product id of that item.

See my code below:

config.xml

```
<wishlist_item_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <data_wishlist_delete>
                        <class>data/observer</class>
                        <method>deleteFromWishlist</method>
                    </data_wishlist_delete>
                </observers>
 </wishlist_item_save_after>
```

Observer.php

```
public function deleteFromWishlist()
    {
        $item = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('item');
        $action = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName();

        if (($action == 'remove') && !empty($item)) {

            $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
            $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
            $query = 'SELECT product_id FROM wishlist_item WHERE wishlist_item_id = ' . $item . ' LIMIT 1';
            $id = $readConnection->fetchOne($query);
            echo 'Product Id: ' . $id . '<br/>';
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
```

The product id is not getting here is because the record in the wishlist_item table is deleting when we remove an item from wishlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can resolve the issue by adding the observer on wishlist remove event **controller_action_predispatch_wishlist_index_remove**

config.xml

```
<events>
    <controller_action_predispatch_wishlist_index_remove>
        <observers>
            <data_wishlist_delete>
                <class>data/observer</class>
                <method>deleteFromWishlist</method>
            </data_wishlist_delete>
        </observers>
    </controller_action_predispatch_wishlist_index_remove>
</events>
```

And update your function in Observer.php to get Product Id like below.

```
public function deleteFromWishlist()
{
    $item = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('item');
    if($item){
        $item = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->load($item);
        $productId = $item->getProductId();
    }
}
```